# SQL how to use JOIN and GROUPBY to display the matching case of a MAX function

Tags: sql, hadoop

I am trying to pull data using SQL Query on the Hadoop server. I have two tables:

t1

```
a  | b | c 
10  143  a  
23  163  g
24  536  r
55  475  a
```

t2

```
d  |  e |
143  bob
086  jim
536  jim
475  bob
```

I am trying to join the t1 with t2, based on their common column t1.b = t2.d and then group the values by e (bob, jim, etc.), and from there pull out max values of a. (max(a) for jims is 24, max(a) for bob is 55).

so far, i am able to join and group by e, but unable to get b to print out as the GROUPBY function is looking for it. it states that it is not an aggregate function. how do i get this to function properly so i am able to query and retrieve a table presenting max(a), b, and e.

```
SELECT max(a) as max_a, e
FROM (t1 left join t2 on t1.b=t2.d)
GROUP BY e
```

This gets what i need but unable to get column b to show without error.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want `group by`.  I think you want window functions:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT t1.*, t2.e,
             row_number() over (partition by t2.e order by t1.a desc) as seqnum
      FROM t1 left join
           t2
           on t1.b = t2.d
     ) t
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```